# Reformat results of pooled imputation results for regression in R

Tags: r, output, regression, imputation, r-mice

I am using multiple imputation on missing data and then using the pool_mi function to fit the results of the imputation trials to my regression model. However the output is not formatted in an easily interpretable way and I am hoping to get some guidance on how to do so. Below is the example code for what I have done with the function and images of the output vs my desired output.

```
library(mitools)
data(data.ma05)
dat <- data.ma05

# imputation of the dataset: use six imputations
resp <- dat[, - c(1:2) ]
imp <- mice::mice( resp, method="norm", maxit=3, m=6 )
datlist <- miceadds::mids2datlist( imp )

# linear regression with cluster robust standard errors
mod <- lapply(  datlist, FUN=function(data){
            miceadds::lm.cluster( data=data, formula=denote ~ migrant+ misei,
                    cluster=dat$idclass )
            }  )
# extract parameters and covariance matrix
betas <- lapply( mod, FUN=function(rr){ coef(rr) } )
vars <- lapply( mod, FUN=function(rr){ vcov(rr) } )
# conduct statistical inference
summary( miceadds::pool_mi( qhat=betas, u=vars ) )
```

Here is the output table I get.
[image]

But is there a way either using stargazer or some other function/package where I can reformat my results so the p-values are rounded and have stars on the side to indicate significance? The picture below demonstrates more of how I want the output to look. I'm aware that the regression in this image is entirely different function/variables/data, but am including it to provide clarity as to how I would like the output for the p-values to appear. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have you found a way how to do this with stargazer since you posted the question? Ideally, I would like to be able to add imputed model results to stargazer like any other models,  like so `stargazer(imp_model1, not_imp_model2, etc.)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how to achieve this in `stargazer`, but it is very easy to do with the [`modelsummary` package for `R`](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) (disclaimer: I am the author).

`modelsummary` supports 100+ models out-of-the-box, but not model objects of class `pool_mi`, which is what your code produces. Fortunately, it is very easy to add support for new models, [as described in detail in the documentation.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#adding-new-models-part-i-)

Specifically, we need to define two S3 methods called `tidy.CLASSNAME` and `glance.CLASSNAME`. The first method returns a data.frame with one coefficient per row and with column names that follow the [standard terminology from the `broom` package](https://broom.tidymodels.org). The second method returns a one-row data.frame with goodness-of-fit or other model characteristics, one per column.

In your case, these simple methods seem to do the job (obviously, you can customize):

```r
library(modelsummary)

tidy.pool_mi <- function(x, ...) {
  msg <- capture.output(out <- summary(x, ...))
  out$term <- row.names(out)
  colnames(out) <- c("estimate", "std.error", "statistic", "p.value",
                     "conf.low", "conf.high", "miss", "term")
  return(out)
} 

glance.pool_mi <- function(x, ...) {
  data.frame(nimp = x$m)
}
```

When we call these methods on the output of `pool_mi`, we get this:

```r
mod_pooled <- miceadds::pool_mi( qhat=betas, u=vars )


glance(mod_pooled)
#>   nimp
#> 1    6

tidy(mod_pooled)
#>               estimate   std.error statistic      p.value    conf.low
#> (Intercept)  2.5875292 0.085702631 30.191946 3.808654e-55  2.41769205
#> migrant      0.5840870 0.087258478  6.693756 1.051145e-10  0.41237872
#> misei       -0.0140385 0.001661665 -8.448452 2.090746e-12 -0.01735046
#>               conf.high   miss        term
#> (Intercept)  2.75736637 22.7 % (Intercept)
#> migrant      0.75579526 13.4 %     migrant
#> misei       -0.01072654 28.2 %       misei
```

Finally, as soon as these methods are defined, the `modelsummary` package should work immediately:

```r
modelsummary(mod_pooled)
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 2.571 |
|  | (0.089) |
| migrant | 0.571 |
|  | (0.086) |
| misei | -0.014 |
|  | (0.002) |
| Num.Imp. | 6 |

Comment: Ok I will give this a shot! Thank you Vincent.